# Css display property not working perfectly in my practice website

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why 2nd div is not up of 1st div. I want they 2 div perfectly set as like my image direction. already i try display block but not working. i don't know why main problem. already i have many research, but all fail. so please help me to solution my problem. advanced thanks and love from my top heart.

`

```css
.testimonial .content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}

.testimonial .content .testimonialBx{
    max-width: calc(50% - 40px);
    padding: 60px 40px;
    margin: 20px;
    background: #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<section class="testimonial">
    <div class="heading">
        <h2>Testimonial</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="testimonialBx">
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit necessitatibus culpa magnam ipsum illum provident nostrum id temporibus? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat similique nostrum harum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime quos quo qui in.</p>
            <h3>Someone Famous <br><span>Creative Designer</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="testimonialBx">
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit necessitatibus culpa magnam ipsum illum provident nostrum id temporibus? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat similique nostrum harum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime quos quo qui in.</p>
            <h3>Someone Famous <br><span>Creative Designer</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

`[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrap those 2 divs in 1 div and make it as flex.

Updated Code

```css
.testimonial .content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.testimonial .content .testimonialBx {
    max-width: calc(50% - 40px);
    padding: 60px 40px;
    margin: 20px;
    background: #2196f3;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>
    <section class="testimonial">
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>Testimonial</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="testimonialBx">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit necessitatibus culpa magnam ipsum illum provident nostrum id temporibus? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat similique nostrum harum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime quos quo qui in.</p>
                    <h3>Someone Famous <br><span>Creative Designer</span></h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <div class="testimonialBx">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit necessitatibus culpa magnam ipsum illum provident nostrum id temporibus? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat similique nostrum harum! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime quos quo qui in.</p>
                    <h3>Someone Famous <br><span>Creative Designer</span></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. you can say me or another way?

Comment: What? Can you please elaborate your concern

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @nagendraNag is ideal. I would just remove the max-width

`max-width: calc(50% - 40px)`;

Comment: by removing this we can't achieve the required output

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).